# Where can I download SignalR.Client.20.dll?

Tags: dll

I want to make multiplayer game in Unity. So I need  **SignalR.Client.20.dll** file . Where can I download this?

Comment: from internet...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can download via nuget package manager.
Link for the nuget manager is https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Client/2.1.2

Comment: How can I download this ?

Comment: Your link showing how to install asp.net

Comment: you just have to add the nuget package to your solution (in visual studio). it will automatically download the dll.

Comment: where I have to add in visual studio? I found nuget package in **extensions and Updates** but  where I have to write?

Comment: Right click on the refrences folder as shown in image [link](https://pictub.club/image/7rv27f) and then in the browse tab search the signalr [link](https://pictub.club/image/7rvG51). You will find your soul-mate there :D

Comment: Kindly upvote if you got your answer

Comment: Looks like I have to update my VS2013. I could not find reference... and ....search tab.